# Why is there an error with a function in C that takes an Array and its size as parameters?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

The function was supposed to take an array and return the largest value in it.

---

```
int findMaxValue(int listName[], int listSize){

    int largestVal = listName[0];
    for (int index = 0; index < listSize; ++index){
        if(listName[index] > largestVal){
            largestVal = listName[index];
            //printf ("%d\n", largestVal);
        }
    }
    //printf ("%d\n", largestVal); it wouldn't even give any output
    return largestVal; 
} 


int main{

    int theArray = {3, 6, 7, 8, 7, 9, 3, 4, 8};

    int sizeArr = (sizeof(theArray) / sizeof(int));

    findMaxValue(theArray, sizeArr);

}
```

I see that the array would become a pointer when passed, but what does the compiler want? I got errors:

```
prog4TSR.c:75:42: note: (near initialization for 'theArray')
prog4TSR.c:75:45: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
     int theArray = {3, 6, 7, 8, 7, 9, 3, 4, 8};
                                             ^
prog4TSR.c:75:45: note: (near initialization for 'theArray')

prog4TSR.c:78:18: warning: passing argument 1 of 'findMaxValue' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     findMaxValue(theArray, sizeArr);
                  ^~~~~~~~
prog4TSR.c:6:5: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
 int findMaxValue(int listName[], int listSize){
```

Comment: `int theArray[] = {3, 6, 7, 8, 7, 9, 3, 4, 8};`

Comment: `int theArray` is not an array, it is a single int. `int theArray[] = { ... };` is an array. Once you fix that the other issues should go away.

Comment: Minor quibbles. Check the size before accessing the array in `findMaxValue` just in case it is empty, and since you're grabbing the first value you can start the loop at index 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
int theArray[] = { . . . . }
```

`int theArray` is wrong the correct syntax to declare an Array is the above I mentioned. If you made the changes then it'll be fixed.